# Anyone used Specflow to do testing of Nservice bus handlers

Tags: nservicebus, specflow

I have one end point deployed couple of service components.
I want to test drive it by writing couple of specs.

I used Specflow to write specs. But trying to figuring out is there any sample around.

I saw the NServicebus.AcceptanceTesting stuff but that is not by Specflow and it has lots of code ceremony to start with. It is not that much straight forward.

Any thoughts on Specflow specs for NServicebus ?

Comment: Rupesh, what kind of testing do you want to achieve? Are you using SpecFlow to have expressive tests but your underlying tests are similar to unit tests? Or do you want to have acceptance tests which also cover larger parts of the infrastructure?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I wanted to do end-to-end testing. Therefore, I installed NServicebus.Testing project in my specflow and using that I invoked endpoint handlers and performed my testing. It was easy and simple.

Answer (score 1):

I installed NServicebus.Testing project in my specflow and using that I invoked endpoint handlers and performed my testing. It was easy and simple

In NserviceBus 5 version I tried this. 
In order to send command I did below in my test case:

```
using NServiceBus.Testing;

[When(@"Create Auction Command is placed")]
public void WhenCreateAuctionCommandIsPlaced()
{
      var createAuction = new CreateAuction(234);   
      Test.Handler(bus => new CreateAuctionHandler(bus))
          .OnMessage(createAuction);
}
```